# Is it possible to create jar that includes android functions?

Tags: android, jar, obfuscation, android-library

As the topic indicates I would like to create a jar library that uses some android functions (no layouts) and that will be included in an Android project.
Is that possible and how?
From the research I've made I managed to include a simple jar file that uses pure Java (JAVA SE 1.6), but
when I tried creating a jar file I encountered the following exception when I tried to run the Andoid app: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mylib.pleasework.amen
I tried including android.jar in my library and removing the java library, so that the jar file is build against android sdk, but it didn't work.
I tried including the jar file under a /libs folder as it is said to be the correct way to import jars in android projects from ADT v17 and after, but that didn't work either.
The jar I want to create will not use any resources (xml layouts, strings.xml) just Log.d and WifiManager.
I am aware of Android Library Project but my library source is sensitive and I am afraid that it won't be safe if exposed in a Android library project. I was thinking of creating a jar and using ProGuard ( http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html ) obfuscate it.
I think I mentioned everything. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did it in the end was: to create an Android Library project (check isLibrary checkbox in project properties) export it through Eclipse (right click on the project->export->jar file, careful to deselect all resources - res folder, androidmanifest.xml, *.png etc) and put it in the project you want by importing it under /libs folder. 
I don't know if this is the best solution but it worked for me.
Used ADT r20, Eclipse 3.7.1, Android api level 7

Answer (score 1):

> As the topic indicates I would like to create a jar library that uses some android functions (no layouts) and that will be included in an Android project. Is that possible and how?

Use the `jar` command, or the `<jar>` Ant task. I am sure that there are ways to export a JAR from Eclipse, but I personally have never used them.

For example, in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) I have a reusable component and a sub-project that is a sample app. My `build.xml` for the repo contains the following custom task:

```
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
    <jar
        destfile="bin/CWAC-WakefulIntentService.jar"
        basedir="bin/classes"
    />
</target>
```

This generates a JAR file, that other Android applications can use by adding to their `libs/` directories.

> I am aware of Android Library Project but my library source is sensitive and I am afraid that it won't be safe if exposed in a Android library project.

It won't be safe exposed as a JAR, then, either. You can create an Android library project for public consumption that replaces the `src/` tree's contents with a compiled JAR in `libs/` in the library.

Comment: Firsr of all thank you for your answer. I already export the jar from Eclipse and when I import it in my Android project, and at build time everything is ok. At runtime I get the exception that I mention above. I don't know if straight ant use will make any difference I guess I'll have to try...in my jar I should include-export android.jar too or not? And concerning security, if I understood correctly, creating a library project and importing the jar will create one more layer of "encapsulation" so it will be more secure?

Comment: @ThomasKa: If you are on R17 or higher of the tools, having the JAR in `libs/` is all you need. If it is not finding the classes, make sure they are in the JAR, are marked as `public`, etc. "in my jar I should include-export android.jar too or not?" -- absolutely not. "creating a library project and importing the jar will create one more layer of "encapsulation" so it will be more secure?" -- once the code leaves your development machine, it is intrinsically insecure. I guessed that your issue was that you did not wish to ship source code, and there are ways around that.